# Problem try to multiprocess on Windows. It works on Noteable

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I can run the following code on my Noteable, but not on my Windows system.
I am using Python 3.8 as well as 3.11.

It also runs on my [Nvidia Jetson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Jetson#Hardware) with Python 3.11.

Here is the traceback without the file location:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 4
      1 if __name__ == '__main__':
      3     V_10k = multi_process_mc_prediction(sample_policy,num_processes=4, num_episodes_per_process=100)
----> 4     plotting.plot_value_function(V_10k, title="10,000 Steps")

File MC\..\lib\plotting.py:32, in plot_value_function(V, title)
     28 def plot_value_function(V, title="Value Function"):
     29     """
     30     Plots the value function as a surface plot.
     31     """
---> 32     min_x = min(k[0] for k in V.keys())
     33     max_x = max(k[0] for k in V.keys())
     34     min_y = min(k[1] for k in V.keys())

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Which means it was not even starting the process.

I try to ask ChatGPT, but it didn’t help.
The code runs well without multiprocessing.

```py
def multi_process_mc_prediction(policy, num_processes, num_episodes_per_process):
    manager = Manager()
    V_dict = manager.dict()  # Shared dictionary for storing results

    processes = []
    for i in range(num_processes):
        #print("i =", i)
        p = Process(target=mc_prediction, args=(policy, num_episodes_per_process, 1.0, V_dict))
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        #print("p start")
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()  # Wait for all processes to finish
        print("lenV ", len(V_dict))

    V = dict(V_dict)
    return V
```

[Here is the notebook](https://app.noteable.io/f/500bf6f0-6d59-4453-a99a-0efb2f206b56)

Comment: Does this create an exception? If so, which one?

Comment: (1) Show an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as properly formatted code in the question. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: There is no multiprocessing in that code.

Comment: What is this "Noteable" you speak of? It is very search unfriendly. Do you have a reference? Something on https://noteable.io/?

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def multi_process_mc_prediction(policy, num_processes, num_episodes_per_process):
    def mc_prediction(policy, num_episodes, discount_factor, V_dict):
        # Your mc_prediction implementation should go here
        pass

    manager = Manager()
    V_dict = manager.dict()  # heres where you put your shared dictionary for storing the results and stuff

    processes = []
    for i in range(num_processes):
        p = Process(target=mc_prediction, args=(policy, num_episodes_per_process, 1.0, V_dict))
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    V = dict(V_dict)
    return V
```

This worked on my Windows computer although frankly the old program wouldn't work on my Mac or Chromebook either.

First, I added the top line, the `from multiprocessing import Process, Manager` in order to import multiprocessing. That was sure not helping.

Second, I just added a `pass` at the end of your functions to, you know, pass it. And yes I added a little commentary too.

Finally, I removed `print("lenV ",len(V_dict))` at it seemed to be unnecessary now.

Most likely, seeing your traceback error and coming to the same conclusion as you, just adding the top `from multiprocessing import Process, Manager` was what it was expecting and stopping it from even starting.